# How to change split sign from html element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, split

I have some `h3` element:

```
<h3>Data Performance</h3>
```

I need to change it to class name: `data_performance`. 
So i do this but something is wrong, can anybody tell me what?

```
var $product_name = $('.subpage_promo.top').find('h3').text().toLowerCase(),
    $product_name_mod = $product_name.split(' ').replace('_');
```

Thx for help.

Comment: just remove .split and see..

Comment: Do you want to just change the space to _ ? then you can do like this right ?$product_name.replace(' ','_');

Comment: this does not help, I will have two classes instead of one

Comment: @Lukas see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HxWdj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using below code.

```
var $product_name = $('h3').html().toLowerCase(),
$product_name_mod = $product_name.replace(' ','_');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HxWdj/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not implementing `replace` correctly. Its syntax is:

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function)
```

It should be executed on a string (you're passing an array of strings), and it should specify both what to search for and what to replace it with (you're currently passing only what should be the second argument):

```
$product_name_mod = $product_name.replace(/ /g,'_');
```

The code above uses a regex, only to be able to specify the *global* flag, which is required in order to replace every space with an underscore. If you know you'll always have just one, `.replace(' ','_')` should do.

Comment: which method is more efficient? yours, or `.replace(' ','_');`?

Comment: @Lukas: In terms of efficiency, [they are very similar](http://jsperf.com/string-vs-regex-replace). Note that they're different in terms of functionality, as is explained in the answer.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Check it out in IE10. String is suspiciously fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h3').addClass(product_name.replace(/ /g,'_'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3D2k/)